# Stdout/stderr file for child process empty, FILE_FLAG_NO_BUFFERING not working

Tags: c++, windows

I'm trying to capture the output (stdout/stderr) of a child process, in particular so that if it exits abnormally, I may get some useful error output.

I create an output file, and set this (and `STARTF_USESTDHANDLES`) on the `STARTUPINFO` structure that I subsequently pass to `CreateProcess()`.

Now I get the following behaviour, for different actions in my child process:

**(1) No flush**

```
printf("Hello world!\n");
```

Result: after child terminated from parent (via `TerminateProcess`): no output in file.

**(2) Use `fflsuh()` after each `printf` call**

```
printf("Hello world!\n");
fflush(stdout);
```

Result: after child terminated from parent (via `TerminateProcess`): "Hello World!" (as expected)

**(3) Abnormal termination**

```
printf("Hello world!\n");
int *p = NULL; *p = 5; // Access violation
```

Result: no output in file.

I could try adding `fflush()` calls after every `printf()` (ick!), or trying to get an alternative to `TerminateProcess()` that ensures the file handles are closed first. But that's not going to help with an abnormal exit - which is the main point of wanting to capture stdout/stderr in the first place.

The other thing I've tried is to create the file with the `FILE_FLAG_NO_BUFFERING` flag set, but my attempts to do that aren't working - `CreateFile()` fails (with error 87 "The parameter is incorrect").  Any idea what I'm doing wrong? Or if there's a different way to achieve this?

I've tried 3 different options for the `CreateFile()` `dwFlagsAndAttributes` value, with the following results.

- **`FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL`** - file is created fine, but I get the behaviour described above (so I miss data on abnormal termination).
- **`FILE_FLAG_NO_BUFFERING` or `FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL | FILE_FLAG_NO_BUFFERING`** - `CreateFile()` fails, with `GetLastError` = 87 and `FormatMessage` returning "The parameter is incorrect". Am I just using the flags wrongly here? Or could it be that this option isn't supported on my filesystem?

Here's the code I'm using to create my output file, and the child process. I've flagged below where I've tried a few different options on for the `CreateFile()` `dwFlagsAndAttributes` value.

```
SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES security = {sizeof(SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES), NULL, true}; // Allow the handle to be inherited by child process
HANDLE myfile = CreateFile(myfilename,
                           FILE_APPEND_DATA,
                           FILE_SHARE_DELETE | FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_WRITE,
                           &security,
                           OPEN_ALWAYS,
                           FILE_FLAG_NO_BUFFERING, // I've tried 3 different things here - see above
                           NULL);

STARTUPINFO startupInfo = {0};
startupInfo.dwFlags = STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW | STARTF_USESTDHANDLES;
startupInfo.wShowWindow = SW_HIDE;
startupInfo.hStdError = myfile;
startupInfo.hStdOutput = myfile;

PROCESS_INFORMATION processInfo = {0};

CreateProcess(NULL,
              executable,
              NULL, NULL,
              true, // Allow stdout/err file handle to be inherited
              0, NULL, NULL,
              &startupInfo,
              &processInfo))
CloseHandle(myfile); // The child owns this now
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: There are alignment constraints when using the FILE_FLAG_NO_BUFFERING option. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa363858(VS.85).aspx One recommended solution is to use VirtualAlloc to allocate the buffer.
Although that wouldn't explain why you get the error in CreateFile.

Comment: Other sites mention that access parameters may also be the cause. What happens when you replace FILE_APPEND_DATA with GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE?

Comment: If you want to disable buffering by CRT, call `setvbuf(stdout, NULL, _IONBF, 0)`. This is roughly equivalent to calling `fflush` after every output call.

Comment: The `FILE_FLAG_NO_BUFFERING` flag is for when you're worried that the operating system might crash or the computer might lose power.  It isn't necessary if you're just worried about the process crashing.  You need to turn off CRT buffering which you can do as Igor suggests.

Comment: Thanks Igor & Harry - removing the `NO_BUFFERING` flag and using `setvbuf` as suggested seems to have worked. I'm still not getting any output from the exception, but I think that's because instead I'm getting a windows "program has stopped working" error dialog, so that's a separate issue.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Igor & Harry for suggesting this approach in the comments.

- Don't use the `FILE_FLAG_NO_BUFFERING` flag. This is only for when you need direct hardware control.
- Calling `setvbuf(stdout, NULL, _IONBF, 0)` at the start of the child process is roughly equivalent to calling `fflush` after each `printf` call. Also call `setvbuf` for `stderr`.